# How could Gordon Ramsay close restaurants in Kitchen Nightmares

Tags: kitchen-nightmares

Ive been re-watching all Kitchen Nightmares episodes lately (nostalgia, I guess) and I have always had the question: How could Gordon Ramsay shut down a restaurant? I mean in what sense does he 'shutdown a restaurant'? Since I don't think he has authority to shut them down himself, then why didn't any of the owners simply refuse to shut down?

Comment: Apart from Tetsujin answer: He's Gordon Ramsey, he's Master Chief and in his world (from what I've read in his books) the main chief have the power to just shut down the kitchen and refuse to cook. For any line cook it would be better to listen to multiple Michelin star winner than a nobody owner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It's a reality show.
   the showrunners have the purse strings & the restaurant owner's full co-operation [whaterver fireworks may be going off, they had to sign something that gives the show the ultimate say]
   The owner is also hoping for a decorative do-over, worth thousands, as 'reward' for their co-operation in the making of the show.
2. See 1.

A late 3. is that some of the violations he discovers would land the owners in court with health & safety issues, hefty fines & potential permanent closure. He is actually doing them a favour by yelling "Shut it down!" no matter how over-dramatically for the cameras.

[Scores on the Doors](https://www.scoresonthedoors.org.uk) wasn't invented back then. Who knows how some of those establishments managed to hide their practices from the health inspectors.

I've actually eaten in one of the restaurants Gordon improved - ostensibly very successfully - which he then revisited a couple of years later to find they'd moved to a new far larger establishment, based on the popularity generated by the first show. Unfortunately they had fallen back into their old habits of pre-cooking everything & flash-frying it for service; not a good way to do it. He tried again to persuade them to change. They did, for a while, but old habits die hard.

He was right, the food was barely edible. They have since closed for good.

Comment: There were several episodes on the U.S. version of the show where Ramsay said to shut down the kitchen, but it wasn't exactly presented as him officially doing that. Instead he told the owner to do it, and if they didn't respond quickly (as presented on TV, at least), he went into the dining area and announced that service was over. In a couple of cases, he showed diners the reasons why he demanded the kitchen be shut down-- even without official or unofficial authority, he could definitely stop people from ordering or accepting food.